# sbt won't assemble Spark

Tags: java, memory-management, command-line, sbt, apache-spark

I am having issues assembling Spark using the sbt on my machine.
   Attempting the assembly without allocating extra memory either runs out or times out on the garbage collector; the exact issue has been different at different times I have tried.  However, any attempt to modify the allocated memory, either through Xmx or Xms, and whether giving more or restricting, fails as the sbt doesn't recognize -Xmx or -Xms as a command.

Here is a sample of the kind of command I have been trying (from the source directory of Spark):

```
sbt -Xmx2g assembly
```

Here is the error I have been receiving:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Use 'last' for the full log.
Not a valid command: Xmx2g
Not a valid project: Xmx2g
Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
Not a valid key: Xmx2g
Xmx2g
     ^
```

I am running 64-bit Java, version 1.8.0_20.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a new environment variable `SBT_OPTS`, with the value `"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"`. That should give sbt the memory it needs without producing your error.

Answer (score 3):

Check the docs: [Building Spark with Maven](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-with-maven.html).

> **Setting up Maven’s Memory Usage**
>
> You’ll need to configure Maven to use more memory than usual by setting MAVEN_OPTS. We recommend the following settings:
>
> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"

Then you can build it with:

```
mvn -DskipTests package
```